# download file from s3 to STDOUT

Tags: unix, amazon-s3

I currently use s3cmd to download a file from s3. However I'd rather output the contents to STOUT. Do you know a unix tool that can do it?

Thanks, Jan

Comment: Try downloading with `/dev/stdout` as the output filename.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to add `-` to the end of you command arguments to make it redirect the output to STDOUT.

Example : `s3cmd get s3://... -`

See [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/s3tools-general@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00130.html) for more information.

You might also use the `--no-progress` option to avoid extra information in the output and just get the plain file content

Comment: perfect. I also split some huge files - any idea how I can stream them at once to stdout? (as pseudocode: s3cmd get s3://mybucket/file-split-* -)

Comment: if you look [here](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/pull/1) you'll find that it's possible to stream multiple files to STDOUT. s3cmd has an option flag '-r' that allow you to retrieve files recursively, but I'm not sure if you can use patterns like '*' to retrieve them. See the [man page here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/s3cmd) for more information.

Comment: You might also want to use the `--no-progress` option to avoid extra information in the output and just get the plain file contents: `s3cmd --no-progress get ...`

Comment: Seems I need the `--no-progress` to successfully pipe an s3 housed gzipped file through `gunzip -c -`. Thanks!

Ex: `s3cmd --no-progress get s3://bucket/file.gz - | gunzip -c - | ...`